# Parent to child SOQL query is not working

Tags: apex, query

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    CurrencyIsoCode, 
    ExpirationDate__c,
    (SELECT 
         Id,
         Regional_Starting_Price_2__c 
     FROM 
         SBQQ__QuoteLine__c) 
FROM 
    SBQQ__Quote__c  
WHERE 
    Id ='quote_Id'
```

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: The child object is incorrect. Please check it once

Answer (score 5):

You're required to write the subquery against the relationship name, not the child object name. The relationship name can be found on the lookup field from child to parent.

Your child subquery should use this relationship name postfixed with `__r` in the `FROM` clause.

For more details, make sure to read [Understanding Relationship Names, Custom Objects, and Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) from the SOQL and SOSL Reference.